# Can you Access Workflow Rule attributes through Schema?

Tags: api, workflow, schema

I need to load the attribute information about a Workflow rule into a custom object.  I need the description, criteria, evaluation rule, and anything other detail about the workflow rule.  Does anyone have code?

Answer (score 1):

Look at Andrew Fawcett's Apex wrapper for the Metadata API. Code on [GitHub](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), how-to on [his blog](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/).

Comment: Thanks for the plug Thomas! Retrieving Metadata is about to become a lot simpler with Spring'14's new 'retrieve' operation, update blog out soon once the rollout completes!

Comment: I have looked at this several times.  I am missing something.  I am seeing how to get fullName, but I need the other attributes. I am trying to map the info.

Answer (score -1):

I figured I post the code I am trying to use and maybe you can point me in the right direction:

This is the line I am erroring on - mapWorkFlowEntity.put(fileProperty.fullName, fileProperty );

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();  
    List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();        
    MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryWorkflow = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
    queryWorkflow.type_x = 'WorkflowRule';
    queries.add(queryWorkflow);  

    MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, 25);
        Map<String,MetadataService.FileProperties[]>  mapWorkFlowEntity = new Map <String,MetadataService.FileProperties[]> ();     
    for(MetadataService.FileProperties fileProperty : fileProperties){
        mapWorkFlowEntity.put(fileProperty.fullName, fileProperty );
    }

    List<Workflow_Rules__c > newWR = new List<Workflow_Rules__c >();
    List<Workflow_Rules__c > existWR = new List<Workflow_Rules__c >();

    List<Workflow_Rules__c> WorkFlowList = [SELECT Id, Description__c, Evaluation_Criteria__c, If_email_specify_recepients__c, 
                                            If_email_template_used__c, If_field_update_what_field__c, 
                                            Is_this_a_time_based_workflow__c, Name, Rule_Criteria__c, Status__c, 
                                            What_actions_are_triggered__c, What_object_is_the_workflow_on__c FROM Workflow_Rules__c 
                                            Where What_object_is_the_workflow_on__c IN: ObjectIds];

    for(Workflow_Rules__c w:WorkFlowList){
        if(mapWorkFlowEntity.containskey(w.Name)){
            mapExistingWorkFlow.put(w.Name,'Yes');
            w.Description__c = mapWorkFlowEntity.get(w.Name).description;
            w.Evaluation_Criteria__c = mapWorkFlowEntity.get(w.Name).triggerType;
            w.If_email_specify_recepients__c = '';
            w.Is_this_a_time_based_workflow__c = mapWorkFlowEntity.get(w.Name).workflowTimeTriggers;
            w.Rule_Criteria__c = mapWorkFlowEntity.get(w.Name).formula;
            w.Status__c = mapWorkFlowEntity.get(w.Name).active;
            w.What_actions_are_triggered__c = mapWorkFlowEntity.get(w.Name).triggerType;
            w.What_object_is_the_workflow_on__c = '';
            existWR.add(w);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't update the question as an answer; edit the question and add in the additional details.